# Exact sequence of USER instruction in dockerfile for non-root user

Tags: docker, devops

What should be the exact sequence of USER instruction inside the dockerfile so that the newuser execute all COPY, MKDIR, CMD on its own while dockerfile execution???

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:12-slim

RUN groupadd --gid 5000 newuser \
    && useradd --home-dir /home/newuser --create-home --uid 5000 \
         --gid 5000 --shell /bin/sh --skel /dev/null newuser


EXPOSE 3000

RUN mkdir /app && chown -R newuser:newuser /app

WORKDIR /app

USER newuser

COPY --chown=newuser:newuser package.json package-lock*.json ./

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY --chown=newuser:newuser . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Does the sequence of USER instruction affects the new user's accessibility inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user):

> The USER instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the user group (or GID) to use when running the image and for any RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

From doc, you could see all `RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT` after `USER` will be affected.

Another word, for next:

```
USER a1
RUN mkdir /tmp/a1
USER a2
RUN mkdir /tmp/a2
```

The `USER` instruction will execute according to the sequence you define them in Dockerfile, the `/tmp/a1` will be setup with `user a1` permission while `/tmp/a2` will be setup with `user a2` permission. So is `CMD, ENTRYPOINT` etc.

**UPDATE according to your comments:**

First you need to understand [linux permission](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/), you can't get ride of this either in container or out of container.

- Next won't work for example:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:16.04
  RUN useradd appuser
  WORKDIR /opt/myfolder
  USER appuser
  RUN touch abc.txt
  ```

  It will report:

  > Step 5/5 : RUN touch abc.txt
  > ---> Running in c942c1e99386
  > touch: cannot touch 'abc.txt': Permission denied

  This is because you set up `abc.txt` with user `appuser` in the folder which setup by `root` with the default permission: `-rw-r--r--`, which aka `644`, that means other user can't setup file in this folder.

  Remember, container things also restricted to linux permission.
- Next would work, as you change the permission of `/opt/myfolder` with root:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:16.04
  RUN useradd appuser
  WORKDIR /opt/myfolder
  RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /opt/myfolder
  USER appuser
  RUN touch abc.txt
  ```

So, this really depends on what you need, in fact, your question is not a docker question, but `how in linux a non-root user could setup/run resource in a root folder`...

Comment: If I am giving USER prior to any other instruction then the commands such as mkdir, chmod, COPY are failing by throwing permission denied or the file not found. But I need to perform all the tasks with the newly added user.

Comment: But when I am running the same commands without giving USER instruction then it is executing properly because I am root here.

Comment: When build there is still a build container there which still limit to linux permission, e.g. you can't touch a file in `/` with nonroot user, it's same as you not use docker

Comment: can you please help me understand the permissions??

Comment: How can I make the CHMOD, MKDIR, COPY operation happen after I pass USER instruction in dockerfile?

Comment: Do I need to CHOWN the new user in every instruction after passing the USER instruction?

Comment: See updated, really depends your real scenario.

Comment: To perform the operations like creating softlinks do I need to do chown? So is that a good practice to do chown wherever file operations needs to be executed with non-root user inside the container?

Comment: If create links in a folder which don't have permission you surely need to change permission. Good or not good, as I said, totally depends on your scenario, we may find different solution if have detail problem, but change permission is a solution.

Comment: I can see that I have added USER instruction in dockerfile after RUN instruction and deployed the application in openshift cluster, pods are up and running. I am logged in to container as newuser.  But I am seeing ROOT as the owner of the directories which I have created inside the dockerfile with RUN instructions prior to USER instructions. So is that acceptable to see the root as owner of the files and directories  or I need to make the entire filesystem of the container as per NEWUSER or in other words making the NEWUSER owner of entire filesystem rather than ROOT?

Comment: But my application pods are running with the non-root user. So, is it enough for the security perspective?

Comment: It's safe, despite of container, this is also in physical linux why software setup system non-root account to protect system. Another word, when non-root user be hacked, it won't damage the things owned by root.

Comment: So may be if the application shows any failure then no need to ssh the container because we dont have any permission to access the filesystem of that container or do any networking level troubleshooting inside the container. So better to deal with it at openshift pod level??

Comment: `docker exec -u root -it container_id /bin/bash` to switch to use root when enter into the container, don't use ssh. BTW, you should post new question if you have additional concern, this make this question too complex. You know, your question in post is `Exact sequence of USER instruction in dockerfile for non-root user`, if have other security question, please post a new one, make the question minimal please. For current question, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to know what should you do.

Comment: I can put up a new question.

Answer (score 0):

A non-root `USER` should be at the very end of the file, near other startup-time directives like `EXPOSE` and `CMD`.  You should not `COPY --chown` files to the non-root user.

This would cause the `/app` directory and the files in it to be owned by root.  That's a good thing!  Since your application isn't running as root, if there's some sort of issue that could cause files to be accidentally overwritten, you won't actually have the permissions to overwrite your application's code or static assets.

```sh
FROM node:12-slim

# Create some non-root user.  We don't care about its uid,
# home directory, shell, or most of the other options.
RUN useradd --system --user-group newuser

# Also creates the directory (owned by root).
WORKDIR /app

# Copy and build the application (as root).
COPY package.json package-lock*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .

# Explain how to run a container based on the application.
# Set `USER` now, but not earlier: the container will run as this
# user, but can't overwrite files in the image.
EXPOSE 3000
USER newuser
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Many Node applications seem fond of replacing the image content with volumes.  If you do this too, everything in the Dockerfile will be ignored in favor of the bind-mounted image content, except that your `node_modules` tree will use an old version from an anonymous volume.  You will need to delete the Compose `volumes:` in order to see the work the Dockerfile does.